# How to override default public key authentication per authorized key in OpenSSH?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I've got OpenSSH server configured to accept public key authentication by default:

```
AuthenticationMethods publickey
```

I'd like to configure some authorized keys to use both public key and password when logging in. Is there a way to override the default authentication methods per authorized keys?

Answer (score 0):

Default authentication method of using public key can be chained with password authentication in authorized keys file of the user `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` by using `command` option:

```
command="su <user>" <keytype> <key>
```

This invokes `su` with the username and prompts for password.

Comment: that is very weird solution.

Comment: This isn’t secure because the user can change his `authorized_keys` file.